# filter table by greater than or equals to (>=)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Sheets("City").TextBox1.Text, _
Operator:=xlAnd
```

What I’m struggling with is how do I get the textbox (Built in the sheet not in a userform) to filter the table by greater than or equals to `>=`

At the moment it will only filter by equals to `=`

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.AutoFilter`'s `Criteria1` also takes operator.

> The criteria (a string; for example, "101"). Use "=" to find blank
>   fields, or use "<>" to find nonblank fields. If this argument is
>   omitted, the criteria is All. If Operator is xlTop10Items, Criteria1
>   specifies the number of items (for example, "10").
>
> [Range.AutoFilter Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

So you can just enter `5` or `>=5` in the `TextBox1`

Comment: Thanks Xiaoy but I dont want my users to add >= in the textbox I would rather have this fixed in the code , so that they could just enter the number

Comment: How about use some radio buttons for this purpose? like 'find exactly', 'find this or greater'; and just prefix with a >= to the value of textbox depending on what was selected.

Comment: Or, if the condition is always greater than, you can just use     criteria1:= ">=" & ...